# Django filter through computed value of 2 Foreignkeys

Tags: django, django-models, filter, foreign-keys

Consider the following:

```py
class Fighter(models.Model):
   ...
   #a bunch of fields

class View(models.Model):
   fighter = models.ForeignKey(Fighter,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="views")
   viewer = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="viewed") #User.viewed.all() returns all View objects of the Fighters the user viewed

class Clash(models.Model):
   win_fighter = models.ForeignKey(Fighter,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="wins")
   loss_fighter = models.ForeignKey(Fighter,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="losses")
```

The key here is fighter_quality = wins/views = Fighter.wins.all().count()/Fighter.views.all().count()
I need to be able to filter this quality, for instance all Fighters where 50% < quality < 80%. I want my Postgres DB to make the work.

I feel like it should be possible via `Aggregate` but can't figure out how...

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: latest version, 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `.annotate(..)` the fighters with that quality metric, and then filter with the given range, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, ExpressionWrapper, FloatField

Fighter.objects.annotate(
    quality=ExpressionWrapper(
        Count('wins', distinct=True)/Count('views', distinct=True),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
).filter(
    quality__range=(0.5, 0.8)
)
```

The `distinct=True` is necessary, since otherwise the quality is always `1`: indeed, since we make two JOINs, and we count the `id`s of the `View`s and the `id`s of the `Win`s, but these numbers always match.

The `quality__range=(0.5, 0.8)` will thus filter the `quality` annotation with the [**`__range`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) lookup with `0.5` the lower bound, and `0.8` the upper bound (both inclusive).

The `ExpressionWrapper(..., outputField=FloatField())` is necessary such that Django understand that `quality` is a float, otherwise it will convert `0.5` and `0.8` to an `int`, and thus check for values between `0` and `0`.